# Android Dialog cannot 'see' final / global variable

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an `AlertDialog`, which for some strange reason cannot access a final int `deptID`.
When passing the value to the `ConfirmRemoval`-function, the value is correct, but when I enter the dialog's `onClick` event, the final int is undefined!

I have even tried to change this to a global variable, but still no luck.
Anybody know what is going on?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    this.setContentView(R.layout.generic_list);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras == null) {return;}
    this.getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adv, View v,
                int pos, long id) {
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor)adv.getItemAtPosition(pos);
            int deptID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("DeptID"));
            ConfirmRemoval(deptID);
            return true; //NOTE! If returning false, the itemClick event will fire
        }
    });
}

private void ConfirmRemoval(final int deptID){
        AlertDialog.Builder bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        bld.setCancelable(false);
        bld.setTitle(R.string.deptRemove);
        bld.setMessage(R.string.deptRemoveMsg);
        bld.setPositiveButton("OK", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                Dept.RemoveDept(deptID);
                dialog.dismiss();
                GetDepartments();
            }


        });
        bld.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = bld.create();
        alert.show();
}
```

Thanks,
Runey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

`Dept.RemoveDept(deptID)` do

`int deptIDlocal = deptID;  Dept.RemoveDept(deptIDlocal)`

Comment: Hey mihail, Thank you for your comment. The problem is, when debugging, deptID gets a value (say 5988), however when I debug in the AlertDialog.onClick event, deptID has no value at all???

Comment: Found the bug!
It turned out, there was a bug in

    Dept.RemoveDept(deptID)

and not the deptID itself. Don't know why the debugger wasn't displaying the value of deptID, but apparently the correct value still got passed to the function.

Weird.

Anyway, thanks for your advise, guys.

Comment: anyway, i didn't see it in the debugger too... but check out my other answear, you may like it :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you have to write your own OnClickListener - something like:

```
public static class processAlert implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
    int deptID;
    processAlert(int _id){
        deptID = _id;
    }
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
         Dept.RemoveDept(deptID);
            dialog.dismiss();
            GetDepartments();   
    }
}
```

and when you create your dialog

```
bld.setPositiveButton("OK",new processAlert(deptID))
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 final int deptID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("DeptID"));
```

Comment: Hey Georgy, Thanks for your advise. Tried it. It didn't work though. :(